# Sending user’s profile picture that I mention in message - discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to send users (that I mention through message) their profile picture. I know how to get profile picture of author of the command but I don't know how to do that for the user I mention. I managed to figure out how to get his ID but now I'm not able to find out how to send his profile picture.

Here is code for sending author’s profile picture:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 10.0, commands.BucketType.guild)
async def hd(msg):
    message = str(msg.message.content)
    if message[-1] == "d":
        await msg.send(msg.author.mention + " You have to mention someone !")
        return
    id = (message[4:-1])
    id = str(id[3:-1] + id[-1])
    if str(msg.author.id) == id:
        await msg.send(msg.author.mention + " You are not able to use the command on yourself !")
    author = msg.message.author
    img = author.avatar_url
    await msg.send(img)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have subclassed commands.Bot, then [Insula's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65872049/12451222) should work fine. If not,

```
@bot.command()
async def avatar(ctx, member : discord.Member = None):
   await ctx.send(member.avatar_url)
```

> discord.Member is a convertor that converts the command argument into a [discord.Member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member) instance.

Docs:
[Converters](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Converter)
[commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.command)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
@commands.command()
async def avatar(self, ctx, *,  avamember : discord.Member=None):
    avatar = avamember.avatar_url
    await ctx.send(avatar)
```

Sends the user their avatar back, see more [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=user#user). I think the problem with your code is that you're not passing the correct arguments.